# How to prove that for any matrix $A$, $A^{T}A$ and $AA^T$ are non negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

I know that for any $A$, $AA^{T}$ and $A^{T}A$ are symmetric, so it's possible that these products are non-negative, where non negativity means that for a matrix $B$ to be non-negative, it has to yield $x^{T}*B*x\geq 0$ for any vector $x$. I could also see that if $\mid A^{T}A\mid=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}$, then given that $n=2k$ where $k$ is some natural number, its determinant would be positive and I know that $A^{T}A$ and $AA^T$ have the exact same eigenvalues. I'm not sure however, where to begin this proof or how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Let $B=AA^T$ in the definition of non-negative and you'll answer your own question almost instantly.

Comment: I think you are trying to prove they are non-negative *[definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix)*

Comment: Try putting brackets into $x^TA^TA x$

Comment: I arrive at the product $x_{1}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}a_{1k}a_{lk}+x_{2}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}a_{2k}a_{lk}+...+x_{m}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}a_{mk}a_{lk}$ if $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. I don't see how to show that this is not negative.

Comment: @Indr Breaking into coordinates is not the way to go, but you've also done it incorrectly since you should get a quadratic rather than linear form. You should probably talk to your teacher to get more guidance. We can tell you the answer (Henry's comment is a breath away from it), but I think your issues with the material run deeper.